# How to concatenate the elements of a list fixing two pivots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a large nested list with lots of elements in their respective sub-lists. The list looks like this:

```
[
 ['Pack', 'my', 'box', 'with', 'five', 'dozen', 'liquor', 'jugs'],
 ['The', 'five', 'boxing', 'wizards', 'jump', 'quickly']
]
```

How can I join the middle elements of the list with a "separator", ignoring the first and the last element of any list size efficiently? For instance:

```
[
 ['Pack', 'my_box_with_five_dozen_liquor', 'jugs'],
 ['The', 'five_boxing_wizards_jump', 'quickly']
]
```

I tried:

```
lst = []

for i in l:
    p1 = i[0]
    p2 = i[-1]
    my_list = i[1:-1]
    new = '_'.join(my_list)
lst.append(new)
lst.insert(0, p1)
lst.insert(len(lst), p2)
```

Although it is working, I think this is not very pythonic and might not work for large lists. Is there any other way to get the above output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
[[x[0], '_'.join(x[1:-1]), x[-1]] for x in lst]
```

where `lst` is your list of lists.

**Example**:

```
lst = [
 ['Pack', 'my', 'box', 'with', 'five', 'dozen', 'liquor', 'jugs'],
 ['The', 'five', 'boxing', 'wizards', 'jump', 'quickly']
]

print([[x[0], '_'.join(x[1:-1]), x[-1]] for x in lst])
# [['Pack', 'my_box_with_five_dozen_liquor', 'jugs'], ['The', 'five_boxing_wizards_jump', 'quickly']]
```

Comment: how fast is this?

Comment: @aywoki, usually a list-comprehension is faster than it's equivalent and that should stay true here as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [
     ['Pack', 'my', 'box', 'with', 'five', 'dozen', 'liquor', 'jugs'],
     ['The', 'five', 'boxing', 'wizards', 'jump', 'quickly']
    ]
b = []
for aa in a:
    b += [[aa[0], '_'.join(aa[1:-1]), aa[-1]]]

print(b)
#prints [['Pack', 'my_box_with_five_dozen_liquor', 'jugs'],
#        ['The', 'five_boxing_wizards_jump', 'quickly']]
```

Comment: is this solution scalable?

Comment: It should be O(N)

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in lst:
    row[1:-1] = ['_'.join(row[1:-1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

would you like to list comprehension

```
[[i[0], "_".join(i[1:-1]), i[-1]] for i in l ]
```